# Modules script and script-private not found in Qt 5 qtquick1 compilation

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qml, cross-compiling

My cross compilation of Qt for Pi fails with the error about script-private (which is present and compiled by me, of course). It seems it cannot find it even when it is there. Other modules installed by the same pattern do not present this error.

```
    $ /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtbase/bin/qmake  "CONFIG += release" 
Info: creating cache file /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1/.qmake.cache
ariel@odin:/opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1$ make -j10
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtbase/bin/qmake /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1/src/src.pro CONFIG\ +=\ release -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1/src»
cd declarative/ && ( test -e Makefile || /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtbase/bin/qmake /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1/src/declarative/declarative.pro CONFIG\ +=\ release -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
Project MESSAGE: perl -w /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtbase/bin/syncqt.pl -module QtDeclarative -version 5.4.0 -outdir /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1 /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1
<srcbase> = /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1 
<outbase> = /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1 
QtDeclarative: created fwd-include header(s) for <srcbase>/src/declarative/ { qtdeclarativeglobal.h (1), qtdeclarativeglobal_p.h (1) }
QtDeclarative: created fwd-include header(s) for <srcbase>/src/declarative/debugger/ { qdeclarativedebug.h (2), qdeclarativedebugclient_p.h (1), qdeclarativedebuggerstatus_p.h (1), qdeclarativedebughelper_p.h (1), qdeclarativedebugserver_p.h (1), qdeclarativedebugserverconnection_p.h (1), qdeclarativedebugservice_p.h (1), qdeclarativedebugservice_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativedebugtrace_p.h (1), qdeclarativeenginedebug_p.h (1), qdeclarativeenginedebugservice_p.h (1), qdeclarativeinspectorinterface_p.h (1), qdeclarativeinspectorservice_p.h (1), qjsdebuggeragent_p.h (1), qjsdebugservice_p.h (1), qpacketprotocol_p.h (1) }
QtDeclarative: created fwd-include header(s) for <srcbase>/src/declarative/graphicsitems/ { qdeclarativeanchors_p.h (1), qdeclarativeanchors_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeanimatedimage_p.h (1), qdeclarativeanimatedimage_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeborderimage_p.h (1), qdeclarativeborderimage_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeevents_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeflickable_p.h (1), qdeclarativeflickable_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeflipable_p.h (1), qdeclarativefocuspanel_p.h (1), qdeclarativefocusscope_p.h (1), qdeclarativegraphicswidget_p.h (1), qdeclarativegridview_p.h (1), qdeclarativeimage_p.h (1), qdeclarativeimage_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeimagebase_p.h (1), qdeclarativeimagebase_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeimplicitsizeitem_p.h (1), qdeclarativeimplicitsizeitem_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeitem.h (2), qdeclarativeitem_p.h (1), qdeclarativeitemchangelistener_p.h (1), qdeclarativeitemsmodule_p.h (1), qdeclarativelayoutitem_p.h (1), qdeclarativelistview_p.h (1), qdeclarativeloader_p.h (1), qdeclarativeloader_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativemousearea_p.h (1), qdeclarativemousearea_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativepainteditem_p.h (1), qdeclarativepainteditem_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativepath_p.h (1), qdeclarativepath_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativepathview_p.h (1), qdeclarativepathview_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativepincharea_p.h (1), qdeclarativepincharea_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativepositioners_p.h (1), qdeclarativepositioners_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativerectangle_p.h (1), qdeclarativerectangle_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativerepeater_p.h (1), qdeclarativerepeater_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativescalegrid_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativetext_p.h (1), qdeclarativetext_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativetextedit_p.h (1), qdeclarativetextedit_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativetextinput_p.h (1), qdeclarativetextinput_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativetextlayout_p.h (1), qdeclarativetranslate_p.h (1), qdeclarativevisualitemmodel_p.h (1) }
QtDeclarative: created fwd-include header(s) for <srcbase>/src/declarative/qml/ { qbitfield_p.h (1), qdeclarative.h (1), qdeclarativebinding_p.h (1), qdeclarativebinding_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeboundsignal_p.h (1), qdeclarativecleanup_p.h (1), qdeclarativecompiledbindings_p.h (1), qdeclarativecompiler_p.h (1), qdeclarativecomponent.h (2), qdeclarativecomponent_p.h (1), qdeclarativecontext.h (2), qdeclarativecontext_p.h (1), qdeclarativecontextscriptclass_p.h (1), qdeclarativecustomparser_p.h (1), qdeclarativecustomparser_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativedata_p.h (1), qdeclarativedirparser_p.h (1), qdeclarativedom_p.h (1), qdeclarativedom_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeengine.h (2), qdeclarativeengine_p.h (1), qdeclarativeerror.h (2), qdeclarativeexpression.h (2), qdeclarativeexpression_p.h (1), qdeclarativeextensioninterface.h (2), qdeclarativeextensionplugin.h (2), qdeclarativefastproperties_p.h (1), qdeclarativeglobal_p.h (1), qdeclarativeglobalscriptclass_p.h (1), qdeclarativeguard_p.h (1), qdeclarativeimageprovider.h (2), qdeclarativeimport_p.h (1), qdeclarativeinclude_p.h (1), qdeclarativeinfo.h (2), qdeclarativeinstruction_p.h (1), qdeclarativeintegercache_p.h (1), qdeclarativelist.h (3), qdeclarativelist_p.h (1), qdeclarativelistscriptclass_p.h (1), qdeclarativemetatype_p.h (1), qdeclarativenetworkaccessmanagerfactory.h (2), qdeclarativenotifier_p.h (1), qdeclarativeobjectscriptclass_p.h (1), qdeclarativeparser_p.h (1), qdeclarativeparserstatus.h (2), qdeclarativeprivate.h (3), qdeclarativeproperty.h (3), qdeclarativeproperty_p.h (1), qdeclarativepropertycache_p.h (1), qdeclarativepropertyvalueinterceptor.h (2), qdeclarativepropertyvaluesource.h (2), qdeclarativeproxymetaobject_p.h (1), qdeclarativerefcount_p.h (1), qdeclarativerewrite_p.h (1), qdeclarativescriptparser_p.h (1), qdeclarativescriptstring.h (2), qdeclarativesqldatabase_p.h (1), qdeclarativestringconverters_p.h (1), qdeclarativetypeloader_p.h (1), qdeclarativetypenamecache_p.h (1), qdeclarativetypenamescriptclass_p.h (1), qdeclarativetypenotavailable_p.h (1), qdeclarativevaluetype_p.h (1), qdeclarativevaluetypescriptclass_p.h (1), qdeclarativevme_p.h (1), qdeclarativevmemetaobject_p.h (1), qdeclarativewatcher_p.h (1), qdeclarativeworkerscript_p.h (1), qdeclarativexmlhttprequest_p.h (1), qpodvector_p.h (1) }
QtDeclarative: created fwd-include header(s) for <srcbase>/src/declarative/util/ { qdeclarativeanimation_p.h (1), qdeclarativeanimation_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeapplication_p.h (1), qdeclarativebehavior_p.h (1), qdeclarativebind_p.h (1), qdeclarativeconnections_p.h (1), qdeclarativefontloader_p.h (1), qdeclarativelistaccessor_p.h (1), qdeclarativelistmodel_p.h (1), qdeclarativelistmodel_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativelistmodelworkeragent_p.h (1), qdeclarativenullablevalue_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeopenmetaobject_p.h (1), qdeclarativepackage_p.h (1), qdeclarativepixmapcache_p.h (1), qdeclarativepropertychanges_p.h (1), qdeclarativepropertymap.h (2), qdeclarativesmoothedanimation_p.h (1), qdeclarativesmoothedanimation_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativespringanimation_p.h (1), qdeclarativestate_p.h (1), qdeclarativestate_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativestategroup_p.h (1), qdeclarativestateoperations_p.h (1), qdeclarativestyledtext_p.h (1), qdeclarativesystempalette_p.h (1), qdeclarativetimeline_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativetimer_p.h (1), qdeclarativetransition_p.h (1), qdeclarativetransitionmanager_p_p.h (1), qdeclarativeutilmodule_p.h (1), qdeclarativeview.h (2), qdeclarativexmllistmodel_p.h (1), qlistmodelinterface_p.h (1) }
QtDeclarative: created fwd-include header(s) for <srcbase>/src/declarative/qml/parser/ { qdeclarativejsast_p.h (1), qdeclarativejsastfwd_p.h (1), qdeclarativejsastvisitor_p.h (1), qdeclarativejsengine_p.h (1), qdeclarativejsglobal_p.h (1), qdeclarativejsgrammar_p.h (1), qdeclarativejslexer_p.h (1), qdeclarativejsmemorypool_p.h (1), qdeclarativejsnodepool_p.h (1), qdeclarativejsparser_p.h (1) }
QtDeclarative: created fwd-include header(s) for <srcbase>/src/declarative/qml/rewriter/ { textwriter_p.h (1) }
QtDeclarative: created version header
QtDeclarative: created master header
QtDeclarative: created headers.pri file
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script-private
make[1]: *** [sub-declarative-make_first-ordered] Error 3
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtquick1/src»
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that

```
 /opt/pi-edis/qt5/qtbase/bin/qmake  "CONFIG += release"
```

Is the in-tree qmake, and that should **not** be used, I was told to use the installed one, this is, the one autogenerated and installed in your host at the same path the ARM should be. In my case it was:

```
 /opt/rpi/qt5-edis/bin/qmake
```

The logic behind this is that the in-tree qmake only has access to qtbase modules, and is used only for buildig and installing basic blocks.

In any case, the correct and preferred way is to compile qtbase and from that point only use the one at your prefix path.